# Python. Получить первое значение словаря

Tags: python

Есть список:

```
apps = "apps_settings_windows":{
    "windows":{
        "coding":{
            "Notepad++":"D:\programs\notepp\notepad++.exe",
            "Python":"D:\programs\Python34\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat",
        },
    }
}
```

Как получить лишь имена программ, а не пути к ним?

Comment: Вы хотите вытащить ключи словаря?

Comment: Да, получив лишь "Notepad++","Python", а не "D:\programs\...".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У словарей в python есть метод [`keys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), который как раз подходит под вашу задачу:

```
test = {
    'foo': 1,
    'bar': 2,
    'baz': 3
}

// Конструкция list используется для приведения полученного объекта к массиву.
keys = list(test.keys())

// Теперь первый ключ можно получить так
keys[0]
```

Comment: а как можно получить пути к программам? Пробовал через `values()`, но выводит и имена и пути.

Comment: `list(test.values())` -- должно работать нормально, причем как во втором, так и в третьем python

Comment: Нет, не напутал. Вывел так: `D:\programs
otepp
otepad++.exe
D:\programs\Python34\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat`

Comment: А я вам говорю, что `list(test.values())` работает правильно. Пруф: https://ideone.com/Ng4CPd Для того, чтобы понять в чем именно у вас проблема, ее нужно сначала локализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Получить первое значение справочника можно следующим образом:

`dict.itervalues().next`()

Comment: В версии Python 3.* у словаря нет метода itervalues(). Лучше использовать `next(iter(d))`, так будет работать в версии Python 2.7, и в 3.*.

Answer (score 0):

```
k = {"опраопар":"рдолдродлопло"}
print(k.keys())
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ["опраопар"] # это вывод

Comment: Такой ответ уже в общем-то есть